# DHCP server box with port-specific configuration

Tags: dhcp

I need a simple but reliable DHCP server with multiple ports, that assigns a port-specific IP-address to clients. It will be used in an industrial setup, where there are multiple rooms with some devices, and we need to be able to access the devices by room=ip-address (please don't ask why!)

Therefore, when the device is connected to the network plug in the room, it must get an ip-address that is specific for that room.

What kind of device can provide this, and how? It should not cost too much, but it must be very reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you'll need to do is to set up VLAN's in your switches for each room, create DHCP scopes and options relevant to those VLAN's, configure your router to route traffic for those VLAN's, and configure your router as a dhcp relay agent.

That being said, any DHCP server should work as most of the configuration is going to be done on your switches and router.

Comment: A further option, if you have a switch fancy enough to do per-port VLANs, may be to run a DHCP server on the switch and assign the IPs that way.